# How can I use Python re.split() to make a list (not dict) of ['key=value', 'k=v', 'k=v']?

Tags: python, regex

Preface: I am not a regex expert

I'm creating a Python script that will parse log messages and create a list of the key/value pairs in the log message.

I have an input string that looks like this:

> **uuid**=00b544de-2c89-4e40-a39f-1ef60f0273ca **version**=3df1e743-439e-49a5-bf12-ba49e54c2a9d 
>   **creationTime**=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073 **lastUpdateTime**=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073 **name**=My
>   Object Name **comment**=create my object **type**=Custom **customType**=SCT
>   **returnValueOnAccess**=true **timeFormatString**=YYYY **min**=49 **max**=20000
>   **specialCharacter**=X **specialType**=BigAndSmall **numberOfBigDigits**=0
>   **numberOfSmallDigits**=4

I would like to take this string and create a list like this:

```
[
    'uuid=00b544de-2c89-4e40-a39f-1ef60f0273ca', 
    'version=3df1e743-439e-49a5-bf12-ba49e54c2a9d', 
    'creationTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073', 
    ..., 
    'numberOfSmallDigits=4'
]
```

I DO NOT want a dictionary.

I would like to use re.split(), I just can't figure out the correct regex pattern to accomplish my task.

We have other codebases that will use the regex pattern we come up with to accomplish the same task, otherwise I would do this in a more Pythonic way.

As you can see, the values can contain spaces, word/digit characters, and punctuation.

I have tried multiple variations of look-aheads, look-behinds, and every regex pattern in between.

Here's some code from my sandbox that DOESN'T work:

```py
log = 'uuid=00b544de-2c89-4e40-a39f-1ef60f0273ca version=3df1e743-439e-49a5-bf12-ba49e54c2a9d creationTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073 lastUpdateTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073 name=My Object Name comment=create my object type=Custom customType=SCT returnValueOnAccess=true timeFormatString=YYYY min=49 max=20000 specialCharacter=X specialType=BigAndSmall numberOfBigDigits=0 numberOfSmallDigits=4'
print(re.split(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=\A))([^\s=]+)=(.*?)(?=(?:\s[^\s=]+=|$))', log))
print(re.split(r' +(?=\w+)(?==+)', log))
print(re.split(r'\s+', log))
print(re.split(r'.*(?=\w*)(?==)', log))
print(re.split(r'\w*(?=\w*)(?==)', log))
print(re.split(r'\w*\s*(?=\w*)(?==)', log))
print(re.split(r'(\w+|\s+)+(?=\w*)(?==)', log))
print(re.split(r'(?=(?:\w*)(?:=))+(\w+|\s+)+', log))
print(re.split(r'(?:(?:\w*)(?:=))+(\w+|\s+)+(?:(?:\w*)(?:=))', log))
print(re.split(r'(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\w+=)', log))
print(re.split(r'((?<=\=).*?(?=\w+=))+', log))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your "list" isn't valid Python. You have a list of strings (simply `log.split() == ['uuid=...', 'version=...', ...]`), but you can't have `x=y` as a value in a list.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put quotes around the list items, I'll fix it.

Comment: What's producing this line: what if the value of `name` contains the word `comment`? How do you distinguish a key from a value?

Comment: @chepner, the keys are always declared as **key=**, and the values are everything after the equals sign to the next key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a positive look ahead in your split to say split by space where the space is followed by some word then an equals

```py
import re
string = "uuid=00b544de-2c89-4e40-a39f-1ef60f0273ca version=3df1e743-439e-49a5-bf12-ba49e54c2a9d creationTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073 lastUpdateTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073 name=My Object Name comment=create my object type=Custom customType=SCT returnValueOnAccess=true timeFormatString=YYYY min=49 max=20000 specialCharacter=X specialType=BigAndSmall numberOfBigDigits=0 numberOfSmallDigits=4"
my_list = re.split(r'\s(?=\w+=)', string)
print(*my_list, sep="\n")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
uuid=00b544de-2c89-4e40-a39f-1ef60f0273ca
version=3df1e743-439e-49a5-bf12-ba49e54c2a9d
creationTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073
lastUpdateTime=2020-02-26 04:09:02.152073
name=My Object Name
comment=create my object
type=Custom
customType=SCT
returnValueOnAccess=true
timeFormatString=YYYY
min=49
max=20000
specialCharacter=X
specialType=BigAndSmall
numberOfBigDigits=0
numberOfSmallDigits=4
```